# UDP, DatagramPacket only receive in a direction, between two computers

Tags: java, udp

I am programming battleship game to play between two computers in the same network using UDP. When I make the conection it doesn't throw expecptions but the information only goes in a direction. I mean, computerA send coordinates to computerB correctly, but computerB doesn't send coordinates to computerA. The code is the same to both computers so I don't understand where is the error. ComputerA always stop in recibeBarcos.recibe(...) method.
To make the connection I use IP of a computer (192.168.1.128) and ports 5000 & 5002

IMPORTANT: If I run the game in the same computer using IP localhost, it works fine.

I translate some variables in order you can understand better the code:
Envia - Send class
tamanioMensaje - message length Constant
Recibe - Receive class
paquete - packet
portaaviones - biggest ship
destructor & submarino - medium ship
lancha1 & lancha2 - little ship
cadenaBarcosAEnviar - ship's coordinates to be sent
cadenaBarcosARecibir - ship's coordinates to be received
getPuertoOrigen() - returns origin port
getPuertoDestino() - return destination port
Those are the basics class.

```
public class Envia extends Object
{
    public void envia(String mensaje, int tamanioMensaje, String hostDestino, int puerto) {
        try {
            DatagramSocket miSocket = new DatagramSocket();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[tamanioMensaje];
            DatagramPacket paquete;
            buffer = mensaje.getBytes();
            paquete = new DatagramPacket(buffer, mensaje.length(), InetAddress.getByName(hostDestino), puerto);
            miSocket.send(paquete);
            miSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception exc) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + exc);
        }
    }
}



public class Recibe extends Object
{
    DatagramSocket miSocket;
    DatagramPacket paquete;
    byte[] buffer;

    public String recibe(int Puerto, int TamanioMaximoMensaje) {
        try{
            miSocket = new DatagramSocket(Puerto);
            buffer = new byte[TamanioMaximoMensaje];
            paquete = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            miSocket.receive(paquete);
            miSocket.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e);
        }

        return new String(paquete.getData()).substring(0, paquete.getLength());
    }
}

public void realizarConexion()
    {
        this.portaavionesCoordsOponente=new String[4];
        this.destructorCoordsOponente=new String[3];
        this.submarinoCoordsOponente=new String[2];
        this.lancha1CoordsOponente=new String[1];
        this.lancha2CoordsOponente=new String[1];

        this.iRecibeBarcos=new Recibe();
        this.iEnviaBarcos=new Envia();

        RecibirBarcos iRecibirBarcos=new RecibirBarcos();
        EnviarBarcos iEnviarBarcos=new EnviarBarcos();

        iRecibirBarcos.start();
        iEnviarBarcos.start();

    }

private class RecibirBarcos extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            cadenaBarcosARecibir=iRecibeBarcos.recibe(conexion.getPuertoOrigen(), tamanyoMensaje);



            asignarDatosRecibidosACoordenadasBarcos();

            colocarBarcosEnPanel();

            iEnviaAtaque=new Envia();
            iRecibeAtaque=new Recibe();

            RecibirAtaque iRecibirAtaque=new RecibirAtaque();
            EnviarAtaque iEnviarAtaque=new EnviarAtaque();

            iRecibirAtaque.start();
            iEnviarAtaque.start();
        }
    }

    private class EnviarBarcos extends Thread
    {
        public void run()
        {
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Espera a que tu oponente esté en esta misma pantalla para empezar a jugar.", "Espera", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            String cadenaBarcosAEnviar;
            cadenaBarcosAEnviar=colocarBarcosMultijugador.getPortaavionesJugador()[0] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getPortaavionesJugador()[1] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getPortaavionesJugador()[2] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getPortaavionesJugador()[3] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getDestructorJugador()[0] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getDestructorJugador()[1] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getDestructorJugador()[2] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getSubmarinoJugador()[0] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getSubmarinoJugador()[1] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getLancha1Jugador()[0] + "-"
                    + colocarBarcosMultijugador.getLancha2Jugador()[0];

            iEnviaBarcos.envia(cadenaBarcosAEnviar, cadenaBarcosAEnviar.length(), conexion.getIP(), conexion.getPuertoDestino());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using two ports? What purpose does the second port serve?

Comment: Mmmm, I think I have to use two ports in order to make it works. But maybe I am wrong, I don't know. If I use only a port, it throws a BindException: Adress already in use

Comment: Then you're doing something wrong. What would you need two ports for? What's using the address when you try to bind to it?

Comment: I don't understand very well why I have to use two ports, I just have learnt it like this.

Comment: If you are doing something without understanding why you are doing it, your chances of doing it right are very low.

Comment: So that's why I write here, to learn how to fix the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Thanks for the support, I have just resolved the problem. The code is ok but I was using the same IP in both computers, so information goes only in a direction. For example:
ComputerA has 192.168.1.10
ComputerB has 192.168.1.20
When I run the game in computerA, I have to write ComputerB's IP
And when I run in computerB, I have to write ComputerA's IP
The ports are ok.
@David Schwartz I already know why I am using two ports. The game has to be client and server at the same time, so It has to have two ports.

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep the socket open for the life of the process, not just open it when you think you're ready to receive. Otherwise if the data has already been sent it will be lost. You can use the same one for sending too.

Comment: I think I understand what do you say, but I am not sure what I have to do to fix it. I am trying to avoid "miSocket.close()", but it doesn't work. Do you think it's better to use a socket only?

Comment: @Seven Open the socket once somewhere in your code. Pass it to the functions that need it or make it a member of the class they're in. Close it only when you're done.